# What model of rear brake caliper do I need?

Tags: disc-brake, identify-this-bike

This old beater bike is missing one part.

[image: old bike]

The front rotor and caliper are there.

[image: front rotor and caliper]

But the rear caliper is missing.

[image: rear rotor]

What model of rear caliper do I need?

If you are able to identify the model (ideally with a pointer to  https://www.bicyclebluebook.com/ or similar sites), do mention it.

I'm also curious about the technical name of hubs that are absolutely silent, such as those on this bike, and the noisy clicking hubs that are on almost all other hubs.

Comment: Not sure on the exact year/ model but the shape looks to be a 2009-2012 Specialized Hardrock. The fork looks better than the original SR Suntour that likely came with it. Earlier models had fatter down tubes and later models got the new logos.

Comment: Whatever you get, make sure it has the right mount interface. The fork uses a post mount, the rear uses an IS mount. You'll probably need an IS/post adapter (I don't think there are any brakes that fit IS mounts directly). Some brakes come with the adapters in the box. But there are also flat mounts, which will not fit this bike.

Comment: @AdamRice the adapter is still on the frame, it's only the calliper that is missing.

Comment: @AdamRice Some do, but they're all out of production now.

Comment: @DWGKNZ I see it now.

Comment: The "silent freewheel" might just be worn and therefore more gentle inside than the sharp-edge clickiness of new pawls.  It is not a new bike.

Comment: If you find a reasonable and affordable deal, consider replacing both brakes with hydraulics.  That way the levers will be the same.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Almost any mechanical disc brake caliper will work as long as it's not a road or short pull model and will also work with a generic 160mm rear IS adapter like the one you have. That might sound specific, but the vast majority of mechanical disc calipers meet those criteria. The cable pull needed will be "mountain", "v-brake", or "long-pull", all different names for the same thing, but it's the more common type so it might not have any of those names in the description.

The front caliper is a random low-end OEM one. There's no point trying to match it.

Ones that would work: TRP Spyke, Tektro Aries, Shimano BR-M416A or BR-M375 (or any other Shimano mechanical brake caliper that has an "M" before the number part of the model number).

If the cable is still moving in the housing freely, all you need is a new brake cable because the one you've got is frayed. If not you'll need a new housing, and there are many questions about that.

"Silent clutch" is the most common name for click-free freehubs. Different companies have made them at different times and have their own buzzwords for the "technology" used. Shimano had an old line of them called "Silent Clutch," then also a newer iteration called "Scylence" that they hyped and then cancelled before widely releasing. The Stealth hub line by True Precision Components are time-tested, ultra high quality, and reliable, but expensive. They're the main option if you want a silent hub to my awareness.

Comment: In my experience the Onyx Vesper is the most popular silent hub. Uses a sprag clutch design.

Answer (score 4):

Any mountain bike disc brake will be suitable for your bike. Personally I would steer away from cable disc brakes and select a hydraulic set. When purchasing a disc brakes make sure you select either a front or rear brake as they come in different cable/ hose lengths.

Comment: Can you confirm that disc brake calipers are front/rear specific? I am not seeing that they are, or that cables and housing are typically bundled with them.

Comment: @WeiwenNg - I'm not sure where you are looking that you don't see that? Mountain bike brakes are sold as sets with lever, calliper and hose. If you would like to buy a component individually you have to buy it as a spare part.

Comment: D’oh. I was looking at the TRP Spyre, which is a drop bar cable disc brake not paired to a brake lever, because ours are integrated.

Comment: @WeiwenNg Hydraulic brakes often come pre-bleed, with left/right lever and front/rear  hose length.  The 'special' bit is the hose length, but getting a 'pre assembled' one makes life a lot easier for the home mechanic.  (Shimano come with the lever not attached to the cable, but you can install them without bleeding due some clever trickery with sealing the barb on the hose end. )   Main thing is get a hose long enough.  In this case, if the OP wanted to only buy one set (Suggest something like MT200's), I would recommend putting a the cable brake on the rear and hydro on the front

Comment: The bike has integrated shift/brake levers (ST-EF series) so upgrading to hydraulic will require new shifters too.

Comment: @JoeK with the laser vision once again, great point!

Comment: There's still the option of having a cable pulled hydraulic disc brake. With the advantage of keeping the same lever on the bar and the possibility of having two moving pistons in the calliper.

Answer (score 3):

Contrary to the other answer, recommend to use a mechanical brake caliper, when your front one is already a mechanical one. Otherwise the investment will be much larger (hydraulic lines, hydraulic brake lever). It would only make sense if you wanted to change the whole braking system (both front and back) to hydraulic. Before that I recommend to compare the investment required with a price of a new (even if second-hand) bike. The front brake is more important anyway so it would make more sense to change the front one to hydraulic first (if not both).

As far as I can see, the bike is ready to accept a **post mount** caliper. If you stay with mechanical, suggest using a caliper that has two movable brake pads, even if they are somewhat more expensive. Most mechanical brakes only move one pad and that is an inferior design.

Oh yes, and it must be an MTB brake caliper, not a road one. Basically, one compatible with your lever. I wanted to write that, but somehow forgot when writing the answer. The only exception would be a lever that is compatible with traditional cantilever brakes or one that can be set to use both pulls (e.g. V-brakes and cantis). As Nathan wrote in his answer, the key term is "long pull".

I do not like recommending any specific products, but the two movable pads recommendation is specific enough.

Comment: You could buy a pair of Magura MT Sport hydraulic brakes or nearly a pair of SRAM Level for the price of one "double pad moving" mechanical caliper so I'm not sure it's such a great recommendation on scales of economy.